# How to display ckeditor 5 data

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display data of CK editor 5 in frontend like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR2Xa.jpg)

Comment: Please [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: It looks like your CKeditor uses the markdown plugin

Comment: that how will I process to show? table not showing in front end ...can you give proper way

Answer (score 1):

The image you provided looks like unparsed markdown. In order to convert this into the correct HTML, you'll need to run it through a markdown parser first. In Laravel, you can actually use the [built-in parser Laravel uses for emails](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/best-way-to-render-markdown-in-views). In your view, simply wrap the output with `Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse()`. For example, if you are currently using `{{ $post->content }}`, then you can replace it with:

```
{!! Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($post->content) !!}
```

The `{!!` is to prevent blade from escaping the resulting HTML.